# Return the last color of the input in Manufactoria

Tags: code-golf, manufactoria

This puzzle is the next in my series of Manufactoria challenges.

## Background

[Manufactoria](http://pleasingfungus.com/Manufactoria/) is a game / two-dimensional programming language.  The player must create programs that will manipulate a queue to arrive at the desired output.  It is easy to learn but hard to master, so it lends itself to creating a wide variety of challenges.  If you don't know what I am talking about, I advise that you play the first few tutorial levels of the game.

## Challenge

Your challenge is to create a machine that will return the very last element of the input string.  To make this even more challenging, the input string can be *any* combination of *all four colors*.

The official custom level to be used is found here:

http://pleasingfungus.com/Manufactoria/?ctm=Last_in_Line!;IN:_a_series_of_colors_OUT:_the_very_last_color;byrgyrbyrrgry:y|bbrrbryyyrrbr:r|ggryybrryr:r|b:b|:|gyrbrygbrygbyrb:b|brbrbryyrygbrg:g|rrrrrrrrrr:r;13;3;0;

This week's challenge is mostly focused on the idea of compression. I chose this challenge to require a huge mess of conveyor belts. The fact that all four colors appear in the input means that it is very hard to store information.

Although I did not attempt compression, my first working prototype had 114 parts and fit into the 13x13 space with almost no room to spare.

## Scoring

The goal of this challenge is to use a few parts as possible.  The score is the number of parts placed, and the lowest score wins.

Although there are only 8 test cases, your creation should be able to theoretically function under any test case.  The test cases provided are for debugging purposes.

## Examples

```
in:  byrgyrbyrrgry
out: y
in:  ggryybrryr
out: r
in:         #don't you love degenerate cases?
out:
in:  gyrbrygbrygbyrb
out: b
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## 65 parts

[image]
To be honest I couldn't even come up with the idea of putting pairs of readers directly against each other until I saw it in the already-posted solutions. But later I started to come up with a lot of optimization tricks.

[Link](http://pleasingfungus.com/Manufactoria/?lvl=33&code=c7:6f2;c7:7f1;i7:8f3;c7:9f1;c7:10f1;c8:6f2;c8:7f3;p8:8f7;i8:9f1;q8:10f7;r8:11f2;c9:6f2;c9:7f0;p9:8f7;q9:9f7;i9:10f5;i9:11f7;b9:12f2;c10:5f3;i10:6f7;i10:7f6;i10:8f6;c10:9f2;c10:10f1;c11:5f0;c11:8f0;i11:9f3;c11:10f1;c11:11f1;c12:3f3;c12:4f3;q12:5f3;i12:6f7;i12:7f6;p12:8f3;i12:9f7;i12:10f6;i12:11f6;c12:12f3;c13:5f3;c13:6f2;c13:7f0;c13:8f1;q13:9f3;i13:10f1;p13:11f3;i13:12f1;y13:13f0;c14:6f3;c14:7f3;i14:8f1;q14:9f3;p14:10f3;i14:11f7;g14:12f0;c15:8f0;i15:9f2;c15:10f1;c15:11f1;c12:2f3;c10:11f3;c10:12f2;c11:12f2;c11:6f2;c11:7f0;&ctm=Last_in_Line!;IN:_a_series_of_colors_OUT:_the_very_last_color;byrgyrbyrrgry:y%7Cbbrrbryyyrrbr:r%7Cggryybrryr:r%7Cb:b%7C:%7Cgyrbrygbrygbyrb:b%7Cbrbrbryyrygbrg:g%7Crrrrrrrrrr:r;13;3;0;)

Comment: ...you can put conveyor belts on top of eachother?

Answer (score 7):

### <strike>73</strike> 69 parts

[image]

Organizing as a strip seems to save a lot of devices.  Left-to-right, the columns are "last color was yellow", "last color was blue", two columns of devices, "last color was red", "last color was green", and "all done".

http://pleasingfungus.com/Manufactoria/?lvl=35&code=c10:8f2;q11:6f5;i11:7f0;p11:8f5;i12:6f4;q12:7f5;p12:8f5;c13:8f0;i10:7f6;i10:6f6;i13:6f7;i13:7f7;c9:6f3;c9:7f3;c9:8f3;q11:9f3;q12:9f3;c9:9f2;i10:9f3;i13:9f2;g12:12f3;c10:10f1;c13:11f1;c13:10f1;c10:11f1;p12:2f3;q12:3f3;c13:2f3;i13:3f5;c11:2f0;c10:2f3;i10:3f1;c11:3f0;c9:3f3;p11:11f3;p12:10f3;i11:10f1;i12:11f5;c14:3f3;c14:6f3;c14:7f3;c14:8f3;c14:9f0;i14:4f5;c14:5f3;i13:4f5;c13:5f3;y11:12f3;c11:13f2;c9:4f3;c9:5f3;c10:4f3;c10:5f3;b11:5f1;c11:4f2;c12:4f2;c15:4f3;c15:5f3;c15:6f3;c15:8f3;c15:7f3;c15:9f3;c15:10f3;c15:11f3;c15:12f3;c15:13f0;c14:13f0;c13:13f0;r12:5f1;&ctm=Last_in_Line!;IN:_a_series_of_colors_OUT:_the_very_last_color;byrgyrbyrrgry:y|bbrrbryyyrrbr:r|ggryybrryr:r|b:b|:|gyrbrygbrygbyrb:b|brbrbryyrygbrg:g|rrrrrrrrrr:r;13;3;

Comment: I've built like five different solutions to this one and they were all over 100 parts in size. Your solution blows me away.

Answer (score 4):

#### <strike>99</strike> <strike>90</strike> <strike>84</strike> 81 Parts

[image: last in line - further optimizations]

Yes - this is a mess of conveyer belts. But finally considerably less than 100 parts - also thanks to Volatility.

http://pleasingfungus.com/Manufactoria/?lvl=33&code=p12:9f3;i12:2f1;c11:9f0;c9:8f2;c10:8f2;i11:8f7;i12:8f5;i12:4f5;i12:5f5;c12:6f3;i12:7f1;i13:9f3;c14:8f3;i13:8f3;q12:3f3;q15:4f7;p15:5f7;c14:5f3;i14:6f1;i14:7f1;i13:7f0;i13:6f0;i13:5f4;c11:7f3;c10:7f2;c15:7f0;c16:5f3;c16:7f0;c11:2f3;c13:2f0;c14:2f0;c15:2f0;c16:3f1;c16:4f1;c16:2f0;c17:4f0;c17:5f1;c17:7f1;c17:8f1;c8:8f1;c8:7f1;c8:5f1;c8:4f2;c16:6f3;c17:6f1;g15:6f0;c8:6f1;c8:9f1;c8:10f1;c9:9f1;c9:10f0;p10:9f7;q10:10f3;b10:11f2;c11:10f2;c11:11f2;i12:10f5;c12:11f3;c13:10f1;c13:11f0;c16:10f2;c17:9f1;c17:10f1;c12:12f3;p14:9f7;q14:10f7;r14:11f0;c15:9f1;c15:8f1;c15:10f2;c11:3f3;q11:4f3;p11:5f3;y11:6f2;c10:5f3;c10:6f3;c9:4f2;c10:4f2;c13:3f3;c13:4f2;c14:4f2;&ctm=Last_in_Line!;IN:_a_series_of_colors_OUT:_the_very_last_color;byrgyrbyrrgry:y|bbrrbryyyrrbr:r|ggryybrryr:r|b:b|:|gyrbrygbrygbyrb:b|brbrbryyrygbrg:g|rrrrrrrrrr:r;13;3;0;

Comment: A little rearranging of conveyor belts reduced this down to 81 parts. [See here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OcM9h.png). Also, changing the colours around seems to make it faster (although it really doesn't matter) from 6:23 to 5:38. See [this paste](http://pastebin.com/7YEytHex) for the URL.

Comment: @Volatility Thank you for the 3 parts. The *seems faster* totally depends on the test cases, so it really doesn't matter ;-)

Answer (score 4):

### <strike>91</strike> 88 parts

[image]

The upper left gadget handles green/blue, the lower right gadget handles red/yellow.

http://pleasingfungus.com/Manufactoria/?lvl=35&code=q8:6f5;c8:7f2;c9:5f2;p9:6f4;q9:7f2;i10:5f7;c10:6f0;p10:7f3;i12:6f6;i13:6f6;c13:11f0;i14:6f6;p14:10f3;r14:11f0;c15:6f0;p15:9f6;q15:10f0;c15:11f2;c16:6f0;q16:9f5;c16:10f0;i16:11f3;c17:6f0;c17:7f1;c17:8f1;c17:9f1;c17:11f1;b10:8f2;i11:8f7;c12:4f3;c12:7f3;c12:8f3;i12:9f5;i12:10f1;c12:11f3;i12:12f5;c14:3f3;c14:4f3;c9:4f2;i10:4f7;i11:4f7;c7:8f2;i8:8f3;c9:8f3;c9:9f2;c10:9f2;i11:9f7;i13:9f7;c14:9f2;c13:10f0;i11:10f6;c10:10f0;c9:10f0;c8:10f1;c8:9f1;c15:7f0;i14:7f6;i13:7f6;c15:8f0;i14:8f6;c13:8f3;c8:4f2;c16:7f0;g8:5f1;y16:8f1;q12:3f7;c13:2f3;i13:3f5;c13:4f3;i11:3f6;c10:3f3;p12:2f7;c11:2f3;c7:6f3;c7:7f3;c11:5f3;i11:6f6;c11:7f3;c12:5f3;c13:5f3;c14:5f3;c17:10f1;c11:11f3;c11:12f2;c13:12f2;c14:12f2;c15:12f2;c16:12f1;&ctm=Last_in_Line!;IN:_a_series_of_colors_OUT:_the_very_last_color;byrgyrbyrrgry:y|bbrrbryyyrrbr:r|ggryybrryr:r|b:b|:|gyrbrygbrygbyrb:b|brbrbryyrygbrg:g|rrrrrrrrrr:r;13;3;0;

Comment: +1 - several ideas: shift the top red/blue divider three places south, you can save the bottom left part (shift one to the left)

Answer (score 2):

## 75 parts

[image: Screenshot of 75-part Manufactoria program to extract last input color]

http://pleasingfungus.com/Manufactoria/?lvl=34&code=c11:9f1;q11:11f3;p11:12f7;g11:13f2;i12:9f1;i12:10f1;i12:11f1;i12:12f5;p13:9f7;i13:11f1;i13:12f5;i14:11f0;q13:10f3;c14:9f0;c15:11f0;c14:12f1;i14:10f4;c15:9f3;c15:10f3;c10:12f1;i10:11f0;i10:10f0;c10:9f1;c9:11f1;c9:10f1;c9:9f1;b13:13f0;c11:10f0;c9:6f2;c9:7f1;c9:8f1;c10:5f3;i10:6f5;i10:7f1;c10:8f2;r11:4f2;i11:5f0;i11:6f4;q11:7f5;p11:8f1;c12:4f3;i12:5f1;i12:6f5;i12:7f5;i12:8f5;y13:4f0;p13:5f1;q13:6f5;c13:7f2;c13:8f3;c14:5f3;i14:6f5;i14:7f5;c14:8f3;c15:6f3;c15:7f3;c15:8f3;p12:2f7;q12:3f3;c11:3f0;i14:3f5;c13:3f2;c15:3f3;c15:4f3;c15:5f3;c14:4f3;c10:4f3;c9:5f3;c9:4f3;c9:3f3;c10:2f3;c14:2f3;c13:2f2;c11:2f0;i10:3f1;&ctm=Last_in_Line!;IN:_a_series_of_colors_OUT:_the_very_last_color;byrgyrbyrrgry:y|bbrrbryyyrrbr:r|ggryybrryr:r|b:b|:|gyrbrygbrygbyrb:b|brbrbryyrygbrg:g|rrrrrrrrrr:r;13;3;0;

Yeah, I know, it's six parts more than [Keith Randall's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12066), but what can I say?  I like the symmetry.